# how to get inner loop value and assign to outer variable

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala. I have started building my skill by writing small programs. In the below code I want to convert raw_features format, but I don't know how to get `transValues` in the inner loop and assign it to the outer `values`.

```
data: dataFrame schema like [id, raw_features]
names: Map ( 1-> "fea")

val dt = data.map(row => {
         val key = row(0).toString
         var values = "abc"
         for((index, name) <- names) {
             val index_value = row(index.toInt).toString
             val transValues = transFormat(index_value, name) // convert format fun
             values.concat(transValues)  
         }
         (key, values)  
     })
```

But the return value contains only `"abc"`; it doesn't contain `transValues`. Kindly let me know where I am going wrong.

Thank you so much in advance !!! HAPPY CODING

Answer (score 0):

Just like in Java, concat() can confuse(!). concat() does not update the string the method is called on, since strings both in Scala and in Java are immutable. It will return a string that you can use to set the same variable (see  jvwilge's answer) or another variable. I think you will get what you want if you return another variable, for example:

```
...
var result = values.concat(transValues)
}
(key, result)
...`
```

Alternatively, you could call `values.concat(transValues)` right in your tuple. Or, thirdly, as Ramesh suggests, you can call += "astring" on the original var.

Comment: And also, in my replacement code, I would make result a val. You are no longer attempting to update the variable values.

Comment: Right, as jvwilge says, you can just set the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

`values = values.concat(transValues)` fixes your code (in place of `values.concat(transValues)`). It now works because of the reason Ben mentions.